# How to read several OWLOntology models in one variable?

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I have a list of ontologies (ListofOntologiesName), I am able to read them one by one. Currently, as you see in my code, I load 1st ontology, keep its classes, axioms, entities, then load the 2nd ontologies and read its classes, axioms, and entities and add them to my previous variables. But, this is not enough. Later, in my code, I need to work with “myOWLmodel” but obviously it only has my last loaded ontology, not all of them. 
How can I read several ontologies in one model?
P.S. I do not want to have a e.g. “Set< OWLOntology > allModell = new HashSet();"
Because, later, it allowed to me to work only one by one of the model of this list.

```
public static void BuildOnt(String ListofOntologiesName) {
    OWLOntology myOWLmodel = null;
    OwlOntologyManager owl = new OwlOntologyManager();
    OWLOntologyID currentOntologyID = null;
    ArrayList<OWLClass> tempClasses=new ArrayList<OWLClass>();
    Set<OWLAxiom> tempaxioms = new HashSet<OWLAxiom> ();
    Set<OWLEntity> tempEntities = new HashSet<OWLEntity> ();

    try {
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        String[] nm = ListofOntologiesName.split("\n");
        for (int ontID = 0; ontID < nm.length; ontID++) {
            if (!nm[ontID].toString().equals("null")) {
                String OntName = nm[ontID];
                File file = new File(OntName);
                myOWLmodel = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);

                Set<OWLAxiom> tempAx = myOWLmodel.getAxioms();
                tempaxioms.addAll(tempAx);      

                ArrayList<OWLClass> classes = owl.getClasses(myOWLmodel);
                tempClasses.addAll(classes);

                Set<OWLEntity> ent = myOWLmodel.getSignature();
                tempEntities.addAll(ent);
            }
        }

        IRI ontologyIRI = IRI.create("http://www.semanticweb.org/mergedontology.owl");
        IRI versionIRI = IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "/version1");
        OWLOntologyID newOntologyID = new OWLOntologyID(ontologyIRI, versionIRI);
        SetOntologyID setOntologyID = new SetOntologyID(myOWLmodel, newOntologyID);
        manager.applyChange(setOntologyID);
        currentOntologyID = myOWLmodel.getOntologyID();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

    //Remaining of code:
   //Do some processes on all Entities by "tempEntities", all axioms by "tempaxioms", and all classes by "tempClasses"
    //Here I need more operation on "myOWLmodel", but it only saves the last loaded ontology
}
```

## UPDATE:

Thanks, I got it., below is my new code:

```
public static OWLOntology ReadMultiOnt(String ListofOntologiesName) throws OWLOntologyCreationException {

    // Create an empty ontology
    OWLOntologyManager MergedManager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    File fileM = new File("NameOfMyMergedOntology");
    OWLOntology MergedOntology = MergedManager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(fileM);
    OWLOntologyManager tempManager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();

    // Load each ontology, and add their axioms to my created empty ontology
    String[] nm = ListofOntologiesName.split("\n");
    for (int ontID = 0; ontID < nm.length; ontID++) {
        if (!nm[ontID].toString().equals("null")) {
            String OntName = nm[ontID];
            File file = new File(OntName);
            OWLOntology tempOntology = tempManager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);

            Set<OWLAxiom> tempAx = tempOntology.getAxioms();
            MergedManager.addAxioms(MergedOntology, tempAx);

        }
    }

    return MergedOntology;
    // After that, I am able to do any process of all axioms, objects etc of all input ontologies
}
```

Comment: Your question is not understandable: *"I won’t to have a e.g. “Set setowlModle = new HashSet();”"* "won't" or "want"?

Comment: What's the problem with having a set of ontologies? If you want to build a merged ontology, what's that: `manager.applyChange(setOntologyID);` - this is useless. Why don'T you add all axioms to a new ontology `mergedOntology` which you create before you load the ontologies? This is pretty straithforward

Comment: You code style is far away from best practice...camel-case style of method names and variable names, the variable names itself should clearly indicate the type of the object, etc

Comment: I have all axioms from the input ontologies in “tempaxioms”, but for any other operations, where I need to call OWLontology model or factory etc. I only have the information of last uploaded ontology. 
For example, “myOWLmodel.getObjectPropertiesInSignature()”  only returns object properties of last ontology.

Comment: Sorry I correct it, I do not want to have a set of owlontology model. For example, if I have 
    Set<OWLOntology> allModell = new HashSet<OWLOntology>();
Then if I call 
    Iterator<OWLOntology> iter = allModell.iterator();
  Set<OWLObjectProperty> seperatedObj = iter.next().getObjectPropertiesInSignature();

For any process, like getObject, it gives me a separated list.

Comment: And you could merge any of those lists into a single list...I don't see the problem here, it's basic Java. Anyways, I told you how to do it. 1) create an empty ontology `o` 2) for each ontology `o_i` that you load, add its axioms to `o`. `OWLOntologyManager` provides all those methods.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused with saving all operations instead of keeping whole ontology. I update my code. Thanks again.

Comment: Instead of adding "[solved]" to the title and editing the question, post your answer and accept it.